# Assetic Symfony not working

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm having some troubles with assetic in symfony 2.

config.yml

```
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: true
bundles:        [ DVMSiteBundle ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
```

head.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/dvmsite/bootstrap/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When i do assetic:dump i get the following

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>                 Warning:preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

When i do a cache:clear

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in /var/www/html/develomaker/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/As                setic/Factory/Worker/EnsureFilterWorker.php on line 54
>   PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in /var/www/html/develomaker/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/As                setic/Factory/Worker/EnsureFilterWorker.php on line 56

When i open up in browser:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in . (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/develomaker/app/cache/dev/assetic/routing.yml").

What does Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 mean?
I cant find any info about that.

When i remove the stuff in head.html.twig and put it in like

```
<link href="{{   asset('bundles/dvmsite/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It all works fine.

Thx in advance!

Comment: does it really write 'As setic' ?

Comment: how is it when you remove "'filter='cssrewrite'" ?

Comment: When i remove "filter= 'cssrewrite'" the error is the same

Comment: Does your config_dev.yml also contain assetic configuration ?

Comment: in the config_dev.yml there is only
"assetic:
    use_controller: true"

I copy/paste the same settings as in config.yml but the errors are still the same

Comment: What files have you under `webbundles/dvmsite/bootstrap/css/` ?

Comment: There are 3 files in that directory:
-bootstrap.css
-bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
-bootstrap-theme.css

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when i used assetic along with uglifycss and had the following configuration in config.yml:
`filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifycss:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/.bin/uglifycss
            node: null
            apply_to: '*.css$'`
I fixed the issue by removing the last line ie., `apply_to: '*.css$'` from config.yml and it worked like a breeze.
Hope it helps.